# Current adder or voltage adder

Tags: voltage, current, adder

Is this a current adder or a voltage adder?

[image]

I just designed it.

Comment: Vout is constant at GND potential, so it's no voltage adder for sure

Comment: If I put the Vout before the resistor (from left to right)?

Comment: KCL tells us that the current through the two diodes has to add up through the resistor. So it would qualify as adding currents. And the voltage Vout would be linear with the sum of the currents.

Comment: you **can** do better photos. And this should be trivial to draw using the built-in schematics editor. The blur you're showing is just kind of lazy?

Comment: ([Here's](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7232/64158) a few hints on taking better pictures of schematics on paper. Your photos are well in the "shot at an angle", "generally out of focus" region.)

Comment: If you don't know whether it's a voltage adder or a current adder, then you didn't just designed it. You drew it.

Answer (score 5):

Neither, if the inputs come from voltage sources. The voltage at resistor output would equal to whichever of the two input voltages is higher, minus the voltage drop of the diode. Of course, if the inputs are not fed with a voltage source, the situation is more complex. If the inputs are driven with current sources, then the currents will add up, but currents would add up even without the diodes so they are irrelevant.

Comment: "Wired OR" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection#The_wired_OR_connection

Answer (score 4):

### Firstly your picture

[image]

---

### Voltage adder

Within constraints it's a pretty decent \$\boxed{\text{voltage multiplier}}\$ but, not a voltage adder unfortunately. So, using two diodes you can get a pretty good linear signal multiplier (modulation): -

[image]

The raw output looks like this: -

[image]

The red signal trace is the modulation; a 10 kHz triangle wave and, the blue trace is a sine-wave carrier at 1 MHz. The diodes allow this sort of thing to happen.

And, if you band-pass filtered that signal you get good old-fashioned DSB broadcast AM: -

[image]

Circuit with 1 MHz band-pass filter as per the above: -

[image]

Other than that it will also add currents because there is nowhere else for the currents to go except to add at the common node.

Comment: OK who's the wise guy with the down-vote button?

Comment: Lol there are always haters no matter how good is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both adders (summers) were invented by Mr. Kirchhoff as early as the 19th century. Both are genius simple because they are made of... nothing. The current adder is just a node and obeys the KCL; the voltage adder  is just a loop and obeys the KVL.

Diodes are nonlinear elements and have nothing to do with these linear analog "devices".

You can visit two Wikibooks stories about the [voltage summer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Series_Voltage_Summer) and [current summer](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Parallel_Voltage_Summer#Deriving_the_simplest_current_summer_from_KCL) to get familiar with the philosophy of the problem.